Azure B2C embedded iFrame login 400 bad request
I got custom policy to handle local sign in, forgot password and Entra ID login in my .net core 8 mvc web app. It is working fine in regular login, however I got a problem when using it with an iFrame. I can login for the first time(when browser cookies and cash are clean) then I sign out and try to log in again I get 400 bad request.
My x-frame-options and content-security-policy:
app.Use(async (context, next) =>
{
context.Response.Headers.Add("X-Frame-Options", "ALLOW-FROM https://my-domain.com");
context.Response.Headers.Add("Content-Security-Policy", "frame-ancestors 'self' https://my-domain.com");
await next();
});
I tried to clear cookies manually on SignOut it did not seem to help.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/embedded-login?pivots=b2c-custom-policy
